# What is Node-API in node.js

Tags: node.js, nodes

Can any one please explain me that what is **Node-API or N-API**?
I am not able to understand this. in which scenario we should use it? or what
is use of this?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html

Comment: i know the link but not able to understand this so asked the question here.

Answer (score 1):

A concise answer is this "Node-API is a toolkit that acts as an intermediary between C/C++ code and the Node JavaScript engine. It permits C/C++ code to access, create, and manipulate JavaScript objects as if they were created by JavaScript code" for further reading, refer to - https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html